# Change font size in xltabular

Tags: fontsize, xltabular

I am creating a table as follows:

```
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}[l]{\textwidth}{X | X | X | X}
    \caption{Table 1}
    \label{Table 1}
    Text 1  & Text 2  & Text 3 & Text 4  
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the font size in the cells? Also, how can I change the column width? Now, all columns have the same width.

Thanks!

Comment: With this code, all columns will have the same width, calculated by the package. Do you want to change the font size for all cells?

Comment: Thanks! actually, I am not happy with an equal cell width indicated by "X". However, I do not know how to 1) change each cell width manually AND 2) make the table span the whole textwidth. And yes, I want to change the font size for ALL cells.

Comment: With this code, the table spans the whole text width (with a small horizontal padding on each side).

Comment: Do you know how I can change the font size for all cells?

Comment: `texdoc tabularx` does show you a manual (and `textdoc xltabular` )  you don't have to make every column `X`, and you can set the font before the table, with `\small`  for example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code to have 1) a `\small`  font size and 2) the second column twice as large as the other columns, with some explanations:

```
{\small
\begin{xltabular}[l]{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X |>{\hsize=1.6\hsize} X | >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X | >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X}
    \caption{Table 1}
    \label{Table 1}
    Text 1  & Text 2  & Text 3 & Text 4  
\end{xltabular}
}
```

The coefficients of `\hsize` are a sort of barycentric coordinates: they have to be proportional to the relative sizes of the columns, and their sum has to be equal to the total number of `X` columns.

Comment: Be careful: the caption is affected by the `\small` formatting…

Comment: That's right. As  there was no caption in the O.P.'s code, I didn't think of this problem. However with the `caption` (recommended for the vertical spacing anyway), it should be easily solved.

Comment: How do I flush left the text in the? Right now the text is fully justified hyphenation

Comment: @Bernard Sure: just add `\normalfont`

Comment: To flush left the text in all cells, add `\raggedright` after `\hsize=xxx\hsize`.

Comment: When I add ```aggedright```I suddenly get the error "There's no line here to end. \end{xltabular}"

Comment: Try adding `\raggedright\arraybackslash` for the last column. LaTeX may have problems interpreting the `\\ ` at the end of rows in fixed width cells.

Comment: I tried ```>{\hsize=1\hsize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X``` for my last column, but the error still appears. It appears in the row where I end the xltabular environment ```\end{xltabular}```

Comment: No it worked! I added \arraybackslash for every column. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The classical column specifiers still work; the X columns will fit the remaining space up to the length passed in the first mandatory argument. You can also specify the format row-wise.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}
    \begin{xltabular}[l]{\textwidth}{|X | >{\small}p{2cm} | >{\huge \bfseries}c | >{\large\itshape}X|}
        \caption{Table 1}
        \label{Table 1}\\
        Text 1  & Text 2  & Text 3 & Text 4  \\
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```